# What is ONE possible use case for the const&& method qualifier?

Tags: c++, methods, rvalue-reference, qualifiers

I award 100 reputation to the person who can show me one **sensible** example of how a `const &&` method-qualifier could be used in real world code which cannot be done more elegantly by using just const& or && overloads.

[Nonsensible example](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:26,endLineNumber:15,positionColumn:26,positionLineNumber:15,selectionStartColumn:26,selectionStartLineNumber:15,startColumn:26,startLineNumber:15),source:%27%23include+%3Ccstdio%3E%0A%23include+%3Cutility%3E%0A%0A%0Astruct+entity%0A%7B%0A++++auto+print()+const%26%26+%7B%0A++++++++printf(%22Hello+World!!%5Cn%22)%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++const+entity+e%7B%7D%3B%0A++++std::move(e).print()%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g122,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B20+-Wall+-Os%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+gcc+12.2+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gcc+12.2%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+12.2+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <utility>


struct entity
{
    auto print() const&& {
        printf("Hello World!\n");
    }
};

int main()
{
    const entity e{};
    std::move(e).print();
}
```

Comment: I don't think there's really a meaningful use case for. R-value references are intended for moving the contents of the referred object out of to somewhere else, but a const r-value reference thwarts this intention...

Comment: From what I've seen, they are mostly use to `const&& = delete;`

Comment: Here's an example: https://godbolt.org/z/n95Gsb8aE